# How to use Typescript to write dojo.declare and inherited function?

Tags: dojo, typescript

I am using TypeScript 0.9 and Dojo 1.8.

Trying to convert the following dojo codes to Typescript, but not very successful.
It is using dojo.declare to create a class. Also using this.inherited(arguments) to call superclass method. Can someone help me to convert this with a d.ts file.

```
// Define class A
var A = declare(null, {
    myMethod: function(){
        console.log("Hello!");
    }
});

// Define class B
var B = declare(A, {
    myMethod: function(){
        // Call A's myMethod
        this.inherited(arguments); // arguments provided to A's myMethod
        console.log("World!");
    }
});
```

A more complicated case with multiple inheritance is:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_Widget",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin".
    "text!/some.html"],
    function (dojo_declare, _Widget, _TemplateMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin,  template) {
        var mod =
        {

            templateString: template,
            constructor: function () {
            },
            postCreate: function () {
                // do something here....
                this.inherited(arguments);
            }
        };

        return dojo_declare("sample", [_Widget, _TemplateMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], mod);
    });
```

Comment: I won't recommend converting from Dojo's class facilities into TypeScript's simplistic prototypical classes.  Dojo's class facilities contain a lot of additional features (including, say, multiple-inheritance).  You can, however, of course continue to use dojo/declare with TypeScript.  The only thing about it is that it won't be easy to get Intellisense on method names for Dojo classes -- you'll have to write your own .d.ts files.  I have Dojo type definition files here: https://github.com/schungx/Dojo-TypeScript

Comment: Stephen, You are right. But I would like to try because TypeScript has nice type checking and I would like to use interface/class contsruction similar to C#. I am surprised nobody has done this before.

Comment: I agree.  It would be best to marry TypeScript's classes with other Dojo modules.  Currently using Dojo classes won't allow you to get type checking on properties (e.g. get/set will return any).  However, you'll need a method to translate Dojo's setXXX/getXXX method of defining properties, which shouldn't have any counterpart in TypeScript.  Also, all of dijit is in Dojo classes, so you won't be able to avoid it there...

Comment: Stephen, I have downloaded your d.ts files and try to call dojo.declare function. 
import dojo_declare = require("dojo/_base/declare"); 
import widget = require("Dijit/_Widget"); 
import templatedMixin = require("Dijit/_TemplatedMixin"); 
var x = dojo_declare("MyWidget", [widget, templatedMixin]);
export = x;

I got an error : Unable to invoke type with no call signatures.

Any idea how to call dojo declare?

Comment: Quick answer: it is ``import x = module("...");``  Using "require" instead of "module" causes your modules to have no type info.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create a declaration file for that existing JavaScript code you'd want something like this:

```
declare class A {
    myMethod(): void;
}

declare class B extends A {}
```

To convert that code to TypeScript you'd want something like this:

```
class A {
    myMethod(): void {
        console.log("Hello!");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    myMethod(): void {
        super.myMethod();
        console.log("World!");
    }
}
```

The difference is one includes an implementation and the other is just signatures.

Having converted some dojo code to TypeScript myself I can tell you that standard TypeScript classes can be extended with dojo.declare classes, but you can't extend a dojo.declare class with a TypeScript class.  Dojo does a lot of funniness that only it knows how to deal with.

Comment: Subclassing will handle the method def. But how do I invoke this.inherited(arguments) within B.myMethod with arguments. Also, I think we need to call dojo.declare to add more methods to each Class to handle dojo specifc functionalities.

Comment: I think maybe I misunderstood what you're looking for.  A .d.ts file is for declarations that describe existing JavaScript code so TypeScript knows how you interact with it.  It only has the signature, not the code.  If you want a TypeScript class that does something like you have that's something else entirely.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Actually I want both. d.ts is easier. But for ts, I can't even compile becasue of this.inherited(arguments).

Comment: I have added a more complicated case with multiple inheritance. How I can transform this typescript 0.9?

Comment: (<any>this).inherited(arguments) will get the compiler to let that statement pass.

Multiple inheritance is not generally a good idea and TypeScript doesn't support it.  Try using composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: Dojo uses C3 method resolution for multi-inheritance. It may not be easy to duplicate this exactly with composition...

Answer (score 0):

I believe your as close as you can get.  You can hand-code an interface in a .d.ts file and assign type to the constructed instances but you can't get where you want to go because dojo inheritance is incompatible with typescript inheritance.  It seems to get this to work we'd have to be able to inform typescript what we mean by "extends", for example, a compiler directive that says objectmodel=dojo.

Answer (score 0):

In dojojs `declare` function is a workaround to create classes so next code:

```
// Define class A
var A = declare(null, {
    myMethod: function(){
        console.log("Hello!");
    }
});

// Define class B
var B = declare(A, {
    myMethod: function(){
        // Call A's myMethod
        this.inherited(arguments); // arguments provided to A's myMethod
        console.log("World!");
    }
});
```

should be equivalent to:

```
// Define class A
class A {
    myMethod() {
        console.log("Hello!");
    }
}

// Define class B
class B extends A {
    myMethod() {
        // Call A's myMethod
        super.myMethod(); // arguments provided to A's myMethod
        console.log("World!");
    }
});
```

For the case of multiple inheritance as you show in the second example, Typescript doesn't support it natively. This means you should use a helper function to do that. For example the code:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_Widget",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin".
    "text!/some.html"],
    function (dojo_declare, _Widget, _TemplateMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin,  template) {
        var mod =
        {

            templateString: template,
            constructor: function () {
            },
            postCreate: function () {
                // do something here....
                this.inherited(arguments);
            }
        };

        return dojo_declare("sample", [_Widget, _TemplateMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], mod);
});
```

you can do:

```
import declare = require("dojo/_base/declare");
import _Widget = require("dijit/_Widget");
import _TemplateMixin = require("dijit/_TemplatedMixin");
import _WidgetsInTemplateMixin = require("dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin");
import template = require("text!/some.html");

// Most likely you should extend _Widget since it is the one which contains  
// the method `postCreate`
class Sample extends _Widget implements _TemplateMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin {

  templateString: string = template;

  constructor() {}

  postCreate() {
    // do something here....
    super.postCreate(arguments);
  }

  // here you should put the overridden methods from the `implements` statement
  buildRendering: Function;
  destroyRendering: Function;
  getCachedTemplate: Function;
  //...
}

// This line is possibly wrong
applyMixins (Sample, [_TemplateMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin]);
</pre>
```

where the function `applyMixins` should look like this:

```
function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
    baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
             if (name !== 'constructor') {
                derivedCtor.prototype[name] = baseCtor.prototype[name];
            }
        });
    });
}
```

PD: The `declare` keyword in Typescript is for creating definition files (`*.d.ts`) not for declaring classes. If you want to make any class, function or variable public you should put before them the keyword `export`.

Answer (score 0):

Hei, i hope am not too late to the party.

Working with dojo and typescript requires you to have type definition files for dojo so that you can use the awesome type checking provided by typescript.

To get these, you can use npm install @types/dojo
Reference https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/dojo

With this you will be able to access dojo types.

```
import * as dojoDeclare from "dojo/_base/declare";
```

Then you can go ahead and use declare.

```
let dojoBootstrapProgressBar = dojoDeclare("BootstrapProgressBar.widget.BootstrapProgressBar", [_WidgetBase], (function(Source: any) {
let result: any = {};
for (let i in Source.prototype) {
    if (i !== "constructor" && Source.prototype.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        result[i] = Source.prototype[i];
    }
}
return result;
} (BootstrapProgressBar)));

export = BootstrapProgressBar;
```